# Зачем нужны dependencies и devDependencies если бабел умеет эффективно делать сборки и удалять лишнее из проекта?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babel

Прочитала множество статей, в которых говориться, что зависимости которые указаны в блоке dependencies добавляются в билд и без них проект не запуститься. Сделала так перенесла абсолютно все зависимости в вебпаке в блок devDependencies и собирала сборки и запускала проект. Запускаться отлично, делаю вывод, что абсолютно где указать зависимость в блоке devDependencies или dependencies. Есть предположение, что `babel "runtime": "automatic`" сам умеет всё контролировать. Если я не права подправьте меня пожалуйста.

Вот пример моего проекта https://github.com/power23421/TestwebpackBabel где все зависимости расположены в блоке devDependencies и он работает эффективно, вы можете перенести все зависимости в блок dependencies и также будет работать эффективно. Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас за сборку бандла отвечает Webpack, ему без разницы. Если WP видит зависимость, он упаковывает её в бандл.

Babel - это:

> транспайлер, который переписывает код современного
> стандарта Javascript (ES2015) на более поздний.